# ajax POST request data lost after # is including in the param data

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

When I send an ajax request from a Javascript function as JSON, where the data may contain '#' in it, the request will lose the remaining parts after '#'.

```
function test() {
    var identifier = $("#identifier").val();
    var description = $("#description").val();
    var fileNo = $("#fileNo").val();
    var prefix = $("#prefixHid").val();

    $.ajax({type : "POST",url : "verification.html?pageAction=onverify&identifier="+ identifier+ "&description="+ description+ "&ddfsFileNo=" + ddfsFileNo+"&prefix="+prefix,
    data : $("#verificationSearchForm").serialize(),dataType : "json",
    success : function(response) {
                if (response.success == true) {
                                } else {
                            alert(response.errMsg);
                            }
                        }
    });
}
```

What I get if the data does not have a # is:

```
http://localhost:8080/pro/eud/pad/verification.htm/?pageAction=onverify&identifier=ddddd&description=vfdfvdfv&fileNo=ddfffd
```

But when I put a # in any of the data (like if I set description to "kjkj12345#6789") then the request will be be like:

```
http://localhost:8080/pro/eud/pad/verification.htm/?pageAction=onverify&identifier=ddddd&description=kjkj12345
```

and the rest of the request will lost from context.

I would expect the request url to be:

http://localhost:8080/pro/eud/pad/verification.htm/?pageAction=onverify&identifier=ddddd&description=kjkj12345#6789&fileNo=ddfffd

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `#` character has a special meaning in a URL; it denotes the fragment. As such, any querystring values following it will be ignored and placed in to the fragment instead.

To fix this you need to encode the `#` when it appears in any values. To do that you could use `encodeURIComponent()`, like this:

```js
var identifier = window.encodeURIComponent($("#identifier").val());
var description = window.encodeURIComponent($("#description").val());
var fileNo = window.encodeURIComponent($("#fileNo").val());
var prefix = window.encodeURIComponent($("#prefixHid").val());
```